# Serial Message Separation

Tags: c#, synchronization, serial-port, communication, microcontroller

I am trying to implement serial communications between a micro-controller and a c# windows application.

I have everything working correctly in the computer to micro-controller direction. But am having trouble working out how exactly to implement communications in the other direction.

My messages are composed of 4 bytes

- B0 – Address/Name of the value being sent
- B1 – High Byte
- B2 – Low Byte
- B3 – Checksum = Addition of bytes 0-2

To make sure complete messages are received, I have the micro-controller give up on the current message being received if there is longer than 20ms between bytes, this appears to work well and can tolerate faults in communications that may cause a loss in synchronisation.

I am not sure how I can implement this delay if at all from within a c# application, as I know you have a lot less fine control over timing.

I have seen other ASCII protocols that send a start and stop character but am not sure how to implement this when sending binary data where my values can take any value possible in the byte, and might happen to be whatever the start or stop character is.

I need to keep the micro-controller side basic as I have limited resources, and the controllers primary task requires very precise (sub us range) that converting ascii to decimal may have.

Does anybody have recommendations on how I should be implementing this from either the microprocessor or the computer side.

**EDIT**
I have looked at some of the other questions on here but they all seem to refer to much larger ASCII based messages.

Comment: For what it's worth, the protocols I've worked with have mostly had designated begin/end message markers, byte values 2 and 3, typically, and then use an escapement algorithm to represent an actual data value of 3 (the end marker) in the data (sometimes referred to as DLE encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty bad idea.  It assumes that the machine on the other end of the wire is capable of providing the same guarantee.  20 msec is no issue at all on a micro-controller.  A machine that boots Linux or Windows, no way.  A thread that's busy writing to the serial port can easily lose the processor for hundreds of milliseconds.  A garbage collection in the case of C#.

Just don't optimize for the exceptional case, there's no point.  Timeouts should be in the *second* range, ten times larger than the worst case you expect.  Make a protocol further reliable by framing it.  Always a start byte that give the receiver a chance to re-synchronize.  Might as well include a length byte, you are bound to need it sooner or later.  Favor a CRC over a checksum.  Check out RFC916 for a recoverable protocol suggestion, albeit widely ignored.  Worked well when I used it, although it needed extra work to get connection attempts reliable, you have to flush the receive buffer.

Comment: This is great advice, but a question, isn't the serial port in .net kernal based when it goes down to the ReadTimeout and readByte functionality since it just wraps the win32 API? also, doesn't windows have a 16ms resolution when scheduling (assuming he has a dedicated read thread with nothing but a loop)?

Comment: Yes.  It is no problem at all when the bytes are in the driver's transmit buffer, it is emptied by an interrupt handler.  The problem is getting the bytes from the user mode program into the transmit buffer.  With a protocol like this, the odds that a program writes one byte at a time are pretty likely.  This is not something you can ever test, it just happens too infrequently.   And if you don't have a way to recover from the protocol fault then that's the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [read timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readtimeout.aspx) to 20ms by using the following command,

```
serialPort.ReadTimeout = 20;
```

This will make the read operation time out after 20ms, in which case you can do what you want.

Don't use `ReadExisting` with this timeout as it does not rely on the read timeout,
instead use [`Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549.aspx) or [`readByte()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readbyte.aspx) and check for a [Timeout Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.timeoutexception.aspx)

incedently the same can be done with [WriteTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.writetimeout.aspx) even on successful writes. so take care on that.